# Macro to reformat section headings

Tags: vba, ms-word

My document has numerical headings that begin with "HEADING|" like this:

> HEADING|1.7.2. My Heading

I need to replace them with a heading like this, where H3 represents a depth of three obtained by counting (\n\.)

> H3 My heading

I'd also like to format the heading using the Microsoft Word style heading that corresponds to the depth.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
Sub ConvertHeading()
'
' Converts
'    3.2.1.3 My header
' To
'    H4 My header
' With the proper formatting
' At depth greater than minDepth, it is converted to
'    My header
'
    Dim iDepth As Integer, iStep As Integer, minDepth As Integer
    Dim sFmt As String, sTgt As String
        
    ' Below minDepth, no formatting or H-code will be used
    minDepth = 4
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
    ' Loop through depth
    For iDepth = 8 To 1 Step -1
    
        ' Style Formatting
        If iDepth <= minDepth Then
            Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading " & CStr(iDepth))
        End If
        
        ' Search String
        sFmt = "^#."
        For iStr = 2 To iDepth
            sFmt = sFmt & "^#."
        Next iStr
        
        ' Replacement String
        If iDepth <= minDepth Then
            sTgt = "H" & CStr(iDepth) & " "
        Else
            sTgt = ""
        End If
        
        ' Find and replace
        With Selection.Find
        .Text = sFmt & " "
        .Replacement.Text = sTgt
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next iDepth
End Sub
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? Most of them allow you to use a function to generate the replacement. It can count the number of `.` in the match.

Comment: In JavaScript or Python, you simply use a function in place of the replacement string. In PHP you have to use `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: You don't even need a macro for this - just a simple series of Find/Replace operations (one for each heading level).

Comment: Sorry, thanks.  I guess I was overthinking it.  I could repeat this several times for different depths or add to the search string and replace string in a loop.     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^#.^#.^#.^#. "
        .Replacement.Text = "H4 "
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll